# get user by id in angular template from angularfire observable not working

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

i have the function to get user by id but it always return observable, but my problem is i have to pass and id to the function form the template in order to get the data i want, since the function isnt an ordinary one i dont know how to do that in angular.

```
/user.service
returnuserbyid(id) {
    const noteDocRef = doc(this.fs, `users/${id}`);
    return docData(noteDocRef, { idField: 'id' }) as Observable<any>;

/user.page
 getuser(id) {
    this.userservice.returnuserbyid(id).subscribe((res) => {
      this.user = res;
    });
```

i want to be able to pass pass an id to the getuser function inside my template and get the details of the user. i an currently using angular fire 7

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to retrieve a user through the id with firebase

- the first one if it is an id defined by default by firebase

  ```
  constructor(private ngFirestore: AngularFirestore) {}

  getUserByDefaultId(id) {
   return this.ngFirestore.collection('users').doc(id).valueChanges()
  }
  ```
- if you give an id to the user yourself (this id is part of the user
  field)

  ```
  constructor(private ngFirestore: AngularFirestore) {}
  getUserById(uid){
   return this.ngFirestore.collection('users', ref => ref.where('id', '==', uid)).valueChanges();
   }
  //end user.service
  ```

> the top two parts are for the user service and the following is used
> in the user page

```
//user.page
constructor(private userservice: UserService) {}
user:any;
getuser(id) {
    this.userservice.getUserById(id).subscribe((res) => {
      this.user = res;
});

//full example

<!-- user component html -->
<form (ngSubmit)="logForm(form)" #form="ngForm">
    <ion-input name="id" placeholder="Enter id"></ion-input>
    <button ion-button type="submit" block>Add Todo</button>
</form>>

<!-- user component ts-->
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

constructor(private userservice: UserService) {}
user:any;
getuser(id) {
    this.userservice.getUserById(id).subscribe((res) => {
      this.user = res;
});

logForm(form:NgForm){

    const id_user=form.value['id'];
    this.getuser(id_user);
    //now let's display the recovered user
    console.log(this.user)
}
```

Comment: How do I use the getuseebyid function inside angular template

Comment: it's in the answer, I just modified it

Comment: so how do i call the getuser function inside the angular template so that i can get the result from the user variable